# What file and directory permissions do I need in my Features directory?

Tags: features, files

I just tried to generate a feature on my test system and Drupal complained that the web server didn't have write permission for the Features directory. I changed the permissions from the normal 750 & 640 for modules directories to 770 and 660 and it worked fine.

I can't see any documentation that says you need to do this so I'm concerned something isn't set up correctly.

Should this work with the 'normal' permissions?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Feature is doing something that's a little bit out of the ordinary ;-)

This is also one of the reasons I have my filesystem laid out as follows:

```
 sites/all/modules/
  - custom // Custom code.
  - contrib // The actual features.module is here.
  - features // This is for my Feature modules.
```

Because this means I can set the permissions on my Features differently to the contributed modules directory. Usually **760** I think. Then so long as the features directory is owned by a group that Apache is a member of, everything should work as expected. I do sometimes have to run a `chown -R` from my Drupal root, but that's because *nix admin has never been a strong point of mine.

Obviously everything on my world facing servers (read: not my local machine) is more secure than this, as should yours be.

That said, on my local machine I always end up forgetting something and just chmodding everything to 775 because I'm in a hurry.